# fopen() is a directory, what must be changed?

Tags: c

im getting the fopen() is a directory and I am unable to locate my error,

**it works perfectly with put and fgets. (Code That Works)**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) // Use a valid prototype for main
{
  char path[256] = "/your/fixed/path/";
size_t len = strlen(path);

puts("Enter a file name:");
// Get the file name leaving room for the path
if (fgets(path + len, sizeof(path) - len, stdin))
    {
    // Strip the trailing new line
    path[strcspn(path, "\n")] = 0;
    }
    // Nothing to concat

    FILE *file = fopen(path, "w");

    // Always check the result of fopen
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Do your stuff ...
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

**I want to use printf and scanf instead of puts and fgets, and when I use the below code I get the reply as fopen() is a directory**

```
        #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) // Use a valid prototype for main
{
  char path[256] = "./casestudy/";
size_t len = strlen(path);
  char *bt ="dd.txt";


// Get the file name leaving room for the path
if(path + len, sizeof(path) - len, bt)
    {
    // Strip the trailing new line
    path[strcspn(path, "\n")] = 0;
    }
    // Nothing to concat

    FILE *file = fopen(path, "w");

    // Always check the result of fopen
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // Do your stuff ...
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what do you expect? you call `fopen( "./casestudy/", "w" );` I guess you wanted to append "dd.txt" somewhere but you don't.

Comment: what is `if(path + len, sizeof(path) - len, bt)` intended to do?

Comment: `char bt ="dd.txt";` is suspicious (and should give a warning) -> `char *bt ="dd.txt";`

Comment: @Techie 1) I have already answered how to adapt the code to `scanf`  in a comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69310049/1606345) 2) Learning by trial and error in C is a terrible idea.

Comment: I edited everyting I dont know why people put this as not useful when im tryin to learn

Comment: In the edited question, where is the call to `scanf`?

Comment: `if (path + len, sizeof(path) - len, bt)` is equivalent to `if (bt)`. Read about the comma operator in your C learning material

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // using valid prototype for main
{
  char path[256] = "./casestudy/";

  puts("Enter the filename: ");

  // Ask for filename from the user
  char filename[256];
  fgets(filename, sizeof(filename), stdin);
  filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = 0;  // remove trailing \n if any

  // concatenate user provided filename to the path
  strcat(path, filename);

  // now path contains the full path to the file
  printf("Full path is \"%s\".", path);

  // FILE *f = fopen(path, ....)
  // ...
}
```

Disclaimer: there is no checking for valid input, if the user provides a filename which is too long you'll get a buffer overflow. I let you deal with this as an exercise.

Comment: The vulnerabilities could easily be prevented by using `strncat`, or probably better in this case: `snprintf`.

Comment: Typo: `filename[strcspn(path, "\n")] = 0;`

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt yes, it should be `filename[strcspn(filename, "\n")] = 0;` instead of `filename[strcspn(path, "\n")] = 0;`